# how to use "not in" operator in oracle cmd?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using this code:

```sql
create or replace view VIEW_MAXMIN as
select c.country_name,
       max(salary) max_salary,
       min(salary) min_salary
from   employees e,
       departments d,
       locations l,
       countries c
where  e.department_id = d.department_id
and    d.location_id = l.location_id
and    l.country_id = c.country_id = not in(select country_name
                                            from   countries
                                            where  country_name = 'Mexico');
```

but always error saying 'SQL command not properly ended'

Comment: Remove the "=" before NOT IN.  But I'm not sure if that is your main problem.

Comment: i am already remove the "=" but it same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the error you're getting in particular is due to -

```
l.country_id = c.country_id = not in(select country_name
                                            from   countries
                                            where  country_name = 'Mexico');
```

You have 2 equals to condition in one filter statement - like a = b = c
Just - `l.country_id = c.country_id` would suffice and `country_name != 'Mexico'` will have to be a separate condition

Answer (score 1):

You can change the joins from legacy Oracle comma joins to ANSI joins and then it looks like you want countries where the name is not `Mexico`.

Also, if you are aggregating columns and have a column that you are not aggregating then you need to use `GROUP BY`:

```sql
create or replace view VIEW_MAXMIN as
select c.country_name,
       max(salary) max_salary,
       min(salary) min_salary
from   employees e
       INNER JOIN departments d
       ON (e.department_id = d.department_id)
       INNER JOIN locations l
       ON (d.location_id = l.location_id)
       INNER JOIN countries c
       ON (l.country_id = c.country_id)
where  c.country_name != 'Mexico'
GROUP BY c.country_name;
```